# how to delete this warning "Please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file."

Tags: java, android, warnings

My my app is working fine but I want to remove this warning:
Please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file."

And please don't reply with don't worry ignore it because I really want to remove it.

Here is my build.gradle (Project) script:

```
type here
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.14" apply false
}
```

Here is my build.gradle (App) script:

```
type here
plugins {
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.ahmedapps.walkthrough_app'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ahmedapps.walkthrough_app"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_16
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_16
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
    def lottieVersion = "4.1.0"
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha01'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.12.0.0'

    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
}
```

I tried updating gradle but didn't work.
I m using 7.5 version

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following line of code:

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
Inside the build.gradle file (Module: app) and not in the build.gradle file (Project).

Try to add after all dependencies.

Comment: it didn't work unfortunately. I have seen same answer on another post and I just tried again and now it is a error not warning. just made it worst.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

so here is what i did to fix it:

step 1: I upgraded my gradle.

step 2: I added this to dependencies(make sure to add latest version):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
```

The implementation above you can find it here:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

step3: I reordered my plugins section to this in gradle.build(app):

```
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}
```

and it is working now 100%.